# finding x and y values of a velocity vector using start and finish coordinates, and speed

Tags: vectors

An example of what I need to do:

Say a boat $B$ to moves in a straight line toward an island $I$, at $S$ m/s.

$B$'s starting coordinates are $(x_B,y_B)$.

$I$'s coordinates are $(x_I,y_I)$.

I need to find the $x$ and $y$ values of $S$.

How would I go about this in a way which works for any values of $x_B$, $y_B$, $x_I$, $y_I$, and $S$?

It's for a little private program/script I'm working on.

Comment: Is the velocity constant or does $S=S(t)$?

Comment: @Bye_World It's constant.

Comment: OK, I was originally going to do it both ways, but I don't think you have enough knowns to figure out $S_x$ and $S_y$ in the non-constant velocity case.  Anyway, my solution is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $S$ is constant, we have the scalar equation $S= r/t$, where $r$ is the total distance between the boat's intial position and $I$ and $t$ is the time it takes to get there.

Written in vector form, that's $(S_x, S_y) = (x_I-x_B, y_I-y_B)/t$.

The total distance (via the Pythagorean theorem) is $r=\sqrt{(x_I-x_B)^2 + (y_I-y_B)^2}$.  Use this to solve for $t$ in the scalar equation.  Then plug that $t$ into the vector equation to get $S_x$ and $S_y$.

Comment: $(S_x, S_y) = S(x_I-x_B, y_I-y_B)/\sqrt{(x_I-x_B)^2 + (y_I-y_B)^2}$

Comment: @tomatopipps I agree.